# QCamera Windows "failed to start"

Tags: c++, qt, qcamera

Fiz um aplicativo com QT onde eu faço a instância de uma Câmera com QT e exibo ela na janela. Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quando eu quero exibi-la em outra janela (QDialog) eu recebo o erro "failed to start". Eu queria que ambas as janelas exibissem a mesma câmera. No Mac funcionou perfeitamente, mas no Windows só instância a primeira, a segunda gera erro. Segue o código que gera o erro:

```
void MainWindow::setCameras(const QCameraInfo camera_info_1, const QCameraInfo camera_info_2){
    if(!camera_info_1.isNull()){
        camera_1 = new QCamera(camera_info_1);
        this->camera_info_1 = camera_info_1;
    }

    if(!camera_info_2.isNull()){
        camera_2 = new QCamera(camera_info_2);
        this->camera_info_2 = camera_info_2;
    }
}

/** inicia as cameras pré configuradas **/
void MainWindow::startCameras() {
    if(camera_1 != NULL){
        camera_1->setViewfinder(ui->cameraVizualizar);
        camera_1->start();
    }
    if(camera_2 != NULL){
        camera_2->setViewfinder(ui->cameraVizualizar_2);
        camera_2->start();
    }
}
```

Quem chama esses métodos, são essas linhas no arquivo main:

```
QCameraInfo cameraTMP_01 = QCameraInfo::defaultCamera();
QCameraInfo cameraTMP_02 = QCameraInfo::defaultCamera();

MainWindow w;
w.setCameras(cameraTMP_01, cameraTMP_02);
w.startCameras();
w.show();
```

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneira: implementei manualmente a renderização da câmera, gerei um QPixMap e exibi em 2 QLabel, pois, no Windows quando acessa-se uma câmera, ele deixa sua instância como ocupado.

Comment: Estou fechando como fora de escopo pelo que foi descrito ser o comportamento esperado. Só dá para abrir uma instância por vez mesmo.